# expressjs - no video with supported format and mime type found error for dash videos

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mime-types, mpeg-dash

I want to embed a dash video in my website.

I follow the guide in [dash-if github readme](https://github.com/Dash-Industry-Forum/dash.js/blob/development/README.md#standard-setup) but the video doesn't work(audio works fine).

**Here is what I get when I do view page source on `http://localhost:3000`:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fa" dir="rtl">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title></title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="/javascripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/javascripts/popper.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/javascripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
    <video id="videoPlayer" controls></video>
</div>
<script src="https://cdn.dashjs.org/latest/dash.all.min.js"></script>
<script>
    (function(){
        var url = "https://dash.akamaized.net/envivio/EnvivioDash3/manifest.mpd";
        var player = dashjs.MediaPlayer().create();
        player.initialize(document.querySelector("#videoPlayer"), url, true);
    })();
</script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Now when I open `http://localhost:3000` I get the audio being played but there is no video and instead I get the error message:

> No video with supported format and MIME type found

However when I do `python -m http.server` on that directory and open `http://localhost:8000/myview.html` the video plays just fine.

I have created my express project with the express command and didn't really change anything except for the template engine that I set to hbs. I run the server with: `npm start`.

By the way I'm suing firefox latest version.